# Show working copy changes inline in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I remember using an extension which showed changes in the left gutter/margin as colours and on hovering over them, displayed what the original code was.

I don't remember its name and cannot find it in the extensions gallery. What extensions can achieve this? I am using Git as my VCS.

Comment: Do you mean "Git Diff Margin" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin

Comment: This is perfect! Please add this as an answer so I can mark as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a extension named "Git Diff Margin" for your reference.

[image: git diff margin]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin